# aspx page using gridTemplateColumn String.Format and need a replace or mask value if exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<radG:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="MyText" DataField="MyText" HeaderText="My Text(Server.HtmlEncode)" SortExpression="MyText">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#String.Format("{0}&#160;", Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("MyText").ToString()))%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</radG:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Here the variable MyText is

```
<?xml......<password>anyvaluehere</password>"
```

Basically I have a LINQ to SQL table where a raw XML value has been stored as varchar(max) and then getting published on a web page. I want to delete the value of in the middle of the tag password or replace the value with `*****`

From my above code I have

```
<%#String.Format("{0}&#160;", Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("MyText").ToString()))%>
```

But my result should ideally be `"<?xml......<password></password>"` or `"<?xml......<password>***********</password>"`

How to use asp.net / C# to get the "MyText" password cleaned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a little helper function

GridView Markup.

```
<radG:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="MyText" DataField="MyText" HeaderText="My Text(Server.HtmlEncode)" SortExpression="MyText">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# ObscurePassword(Eval("MyText"))%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</radG:GridTemplateColumn>
```

On code-behind.

```
//Warning: minimal code, no error catching mechanisms included.
protected string ObscurePassword(object xmlObj)
{
    //var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><main><blah>some value</blah><password>anyvaluehere</password></main>";
    var xml = xmlObj.ToString();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    XElement elm = doc.Descendants("password").First();
    elm.Value = "*****";
    //elm.ReplaceWith(new XElement("password", "*****"));
    var encodedDoc = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(doc.ToString());
    //var encodedDoc = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(doc.ToString());
    return encodedDoc;
}
```

**Update**: If you are using a namespace, ie, xmlns, add that too while querying like this

```
XNamespace xmlns = "http://yoyo.net/";
XElement elm = doc.Descendants(xmlns + "password").First();
```

Or

```
string xmlns = "http://yoyo.net/";
XElement elm = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("Stuff", xmlns)).First();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I want... I'm new to XDocumnet and trying the code behind I'm getting the error: Sequence contains no elements at  XElement elm = doc.Descendants("password").First(); 

the doc = <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">; <soap:Body> <Stuff xmlns="yoyo.net/">; <data> <transaction> <password>anyvaluehere</password> <type>aType</type> ...

Comment: Thank You!  That works ! XNamespace xmlns = "http://yoyo.net/";
XElement elm = doc.Descendants(xmlns + "password").First();